# prevent printing sheet if cells are specific color

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a spreadsheet which I currently use as a form which I would like to make it impossible to print if specific cells are not filled out.  The problem is that I have other macros in the sheet which move around rows dependent on user input.  So I can't specifically check certain cells to see if they are empty.  I figured I could use conditional formatting to assign a certain color if a field is unlocked and empty and just check each cell in the used range for the presence of that color to prevent printing.  However what I built just isn't working.  It doesn't provide and error and it doesn't stop printing either.  If anyone could help out I would greatly appreciate it.  Here is what I have been working with.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rRng As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Set rRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2Name").UsedRange
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1Name" Then Exit Sub
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet2Name" Then
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If rCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "All required cells are not filled out, please see supervisor for assistance"
        End If
    Next rCell
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me as is.  Are you sure that the color is correct?  It may be easier to find if a cell color is <> to RGB(255,255,255)

Comment: Yeah total brain fart, I put in the wrong RGB value.  Thanks for looking into the problem.

Comment: Just FYI - you don't really need the first `If Sheet = Sheet1Name then exit` line, since the next one checks if it's "Sheet2Name" before running. You may also want to adjust using `UsedRange`, since I've heard that can be a little finnicky at times.  Change that to some range you *know* has a Green cell, and see if it works then.  If so, we know it's an issue with `UsedRange`.  edit: Or of course, it's Friday and our brains have all checked out for the weekend :P